# Pygame - Update tiles taken by enemy characters

Tags: python

### Problem

I have a scrolling game with 250+ enemy aliens and I want to implement basic crowd behaviour and maybe even Goal-Oriented Pathfinding.
For that I thought that implementing a tile system would be the best. The problem is that getting the location of each alien and using it to "block" the tile it is on, is way too slow with my implementation.
Can you help me with a better implementation or a good concept on how to achieve better performance?

### Setup

I created a tilemap, which is an array, `self.tiles`, containing the tiles as dictionaries with each tile being a 16px rectangle. (each alien is around 16px wide).
In order to retrieve each tile, I have an array, `self.chunks_location`,  containing all tile coordinates.

Each alien passes its (x,y) to the function below, converting its (x,y) to multipel of 16.
The converted (x,y) gets then looked up in `self.chunks_location` and the retrieved index is used to block the corresponding tile inside `self.tiles`.

---

**Function: Convert (x,y)**

(The function was originally intended to output multiple tile coordinates, if the alien is right between two tiles, so it looks a bit weird right now.)

```
def get_chunks_from_cord(self, x, y):
    """
    Returns the chunk or chunks for the given location on the map, based on the tilesize of the map.
    Being in between chunks leads to multiple chunks being returned.

    (float or int) -> [tuple(int, int)]
    (20, 58)    ->  [[16, 68]]
    """

    """
    Adds the cords separate rounded to 16 to tilesize coordinates to the blocked list.
    """

    decimal_16 = [x % self.chunksize, y % self.chunksize]
    blocked = [[], []]  # [[x values], [y values]]
    for cnt, cord in enumerate((x, y)):
        if decimal_16[cnt] >= self.chunksize_05:
            blocked[cnt].append(cord + self.chunksize - decimal_16[cnt])
        else:
            blocked[cnt].append(cord - decimal_16[cnt])


    result = []
    for array in blocked[0]:
        for var in blocked[1]:
            result.append((round(array), round(var)))

    return result
```

**Function block tile**

Block tiles based on the previously converted coordinates.

```py
def block_chunks(self, array):
        if len(array) == 1:
            target = self.chunks_location.index(array[0])
            self.chunks[target]["blocked"] = True
            self.chunks_blocked.append(self.chunks[target])
        else:
            for cords in array:
                target = self.chunks_location.index(cords)
                self.chunks[target]["blocked"] = True
                self.chunks_blocked.append(self.chunks[target])
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.